# How do I validate nested attributes using reform + dry-validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, reform, trailblazer

Validations are triggered and work as expected for attributes of the record I'm passing in (i.e `required(:title).filled`), but not for attributes of nested models (i.e `required(:name).filled` in `artist`).

```
class AlbumForm < Reform::Form
  property :title

  validation do
   required(:title).filled
  end

  property :artist do
    property :name

    validation do
     required(:name).filled
    end
  end
end
```

(Snippet taken from http://trailblazer.to/gems/reform)

I expect `Albumform.new(album).valid?` to return false if `album.artist.name == nil` but it does not. What am I missing here? How can this be achieved?

Using:

- rails 4.2.7.1
- reform-rails 0.1.7
- reform 2.2.2
- dry-validation 0.10.3

Answer (score 2):

Long story short you should be using `validate(params[:album])` instead of `valid?`
http://trailblazer.to/gems/reform/#validation

```
def create 
  # params album: { name: nil, other_stuff: 'stuff' }

  form = AlbumForm.new(Album.new)
  if form.validate(params[:album])
    form.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Links appear to be dead, over here now? https://trailblazer.to/2.0/gems/reform/validation.html